# Interlocked.Increment in finally block

Tags: c#, .net, try-finally, .net-core

Looking through the sources of .NET Core, I've found the following piece in `ConcurrentQueue<T>` [source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/4a3d2d5b7b53a6d37fcc54553f5d0f62b2d6cff7/src/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs):

```
//We need do Interlocked.Increment and value/state update in a finally block to ensure that they run
//without interuption. This is to prevent anything from happening between them, and another dequeue
//thread maybe spinning forever to wait for _state[] to be true;
try
{ }
finally
{
    newhigh = Interlocked.Increment(ref _high);
    if (newhigh <= SEGMENT_SIZE - 1)
    {
        _array[newhigh] = value;
        _state[newhigh]._value = true;
    }

    //if this thread takes up the last slot in the segment, then this thread is responsible
    //to grow a new segment. Calling Grow must be in the finally block too for reliability reason:
    //if thread abort during Grow, other threads will be left busy spinning forever.
    if (newhigh == SEGMENT_SIZE - 1)
    {
        Grow();
    }
}
```

So the question is what the purpose is of an empty `try` block here and putting that code into a `finally` block?

Comment: That comment reads: `We need do Interlocked.Increment and value/state update in a finally block to ensure that they run without interuption. This is to prevent anything from happening between them, and another dequeue
thread maybe spinning forever to wait for _state[] to be true`.